# LU Factorization benefits over augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We learned that in this method we store all the information needed (inside L matrix) to convert an A matrix into an upper triangular one (U matrix). Therefore, for different b's of the equation $Ax=b$ and the same matrix A, we can directly by forward and backward substitution determine the solution of the system each time, without having to repeat the process of triangulation again and again (I hope I'm right so far).

But if we know the b's in advance (ie $b_1\,\,b_2 \,\,...\,\, b_n$), in order to solve the equations $Αx=b1,\,\, Ax=b2,\,\, Ax=bn$ isn't it faster to consider the augmented matrix $[A|\,\, b_1\,\,b_2 \,\,...\,\, b_n]$ and proceed by triangulating once and then do back substitutions for each b ?

Thanks in advance.